# Automapper to map child tables

Tags: automapper

I have 3 tables in my database and these are the classes:

```
public class PRAT
{
    public PRAT()
    {
        PRAT_RIC = new HashSet<PRAT_RIC>();
    }
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string PRATICA { get; set; }
    public int ANNO { get; set; }
    public string VARIANTE { get; set; }
    [...] other fields
}
public class PRAT_RIC
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int IDPRAT { get; set; }
    public int IDANAG { get; set; }
    public int? IDTITRIC { get; set; }
    public virtual ANAGRAFI IDANAGNavigation { get; set; }
}

public class ANAGRAFI
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string TIPO { get; set; }
    public string TITOLO { get; set; }
    public string COGNOME { get; set; }
    public string NOME { get; set; }
    public string CODFISC { get; set; }
}
```

So, the relations are:
Prat -> Prat_Ric (Prat.Id=Prat_Ric.IdPrat) -> Anagrafi (Anagrafi.Id=Prat_Ric.IdAnag)

These are the destination classes:

```
public class PraticaResource
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string PRATICA { get; set; }
    public int ANNO { get; set; }
    public string VARIANTE { get; set; }
    public ICollection<RichiedentiResource> RICHIEDENTI { get; set; }
}

public class RichiedentiResource
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int IDANAG { get; set; }
    public string TITOLO { get; set; }
    public string COGNOME { get; set; }
    public string NOME { get; set; }
    public string CODFISC { get; set; }
    public string TITRIC { get; set; }
}
```

I created the map with

```
CreateMap<PRAT_RIC, RichiedentiResource>()
    .ForMember(p => p.COGNOME, opt => opt.MapFrom(ti => ti.IDANAGNavigation.COGNOME))
    .ForMember(p => p.NOME, opt => opt.MapFrom(ti => ti.IDANAGNavigation.NOME));
```

Is it possible to map all the properties of RichiedentiResource to the ANAGRAFI fields with the same name so that i haven't to write every single field mapping?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need anything from the navigation class, then you can just skip it when mapping at the top level:

```
CreateMap<PRAT, PraticaResource>()
    .ForMember(p => p.PRAT_RIC, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.PRAT_RIC.Select(x => x.IDANAGNavigation))
```

Then you just need the mapping from `ANAGRAFI` -> `RichiedentiResource`, which should work out the field mappings automatically.

Comment: Thank you Richard for your help.
With your code I got this error:
CS1061 ICollection<PRAT_RIC> does not contain a definition for 'Select' and no extension method 'Select' accepting a first argument of type  ICollection<PRAT_RIC> could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Sorry... using Linq missing. Thank you